# Adding additional checks and DbContext to Identity FindByEmail and FindByUserName

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

The app I am working on uses .NET Core Identity 3 and we want to add some custom functionality when deleting users.

Our ApplicationUser class has a boolean IsDeleted flag and when "deleting" a user we want to just set this flag and not actually delete the record from the AspNetUsers table.

We also have a requirement to have a unique email address and username, and so we want the same basic user validation behaviour as Identity gives you out of the box....the problem here obviously is that when a user has been marked as inactive, to us that means they should be considered as deleted.  So you should be able to create another user with the same email or username, as long as any existing users with the isDeleted flag are set to true.

The built in UserValidator behaviour knows nothing about our IsDeleting field.

I basically want to override the FindByEmailAsync and FindByUserName async and add in a check for the isDeleting flag.

What is the cleanest way to implement this? I am not sure where to start with all the interdepenencies of Identity.

Looking for a nudge in the correct direction....

Comment: Replace the user store: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Service.EntityFrameworkCore/ApplicationStore.cs#L15 or implement  inherit from DbContext https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318009/455493 (example just shows how to write/update an IsDeleted/CreatedOn Property though

Comment: But EF Core 2.0 will allow [global filters](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap): _**Filtered loading** allows a subset of related entities to be loaded. This has been addressed by global query filters in EF Core 2.0 Preview 1__