# Entity Framework writes in Context but not Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2017-express

We use an UnitOfWork approach for an application based on EF 6.2.0 in C# with a SQL Server 2017 Express (14.0.1000) database backend.

Our `OwnContext.cs` inherited from `DbContext` should fill the fields `Id`, `ChangedDate` and `ChangedUser` automatically, which is part of every entity in our db model:

```
public partial class OwnContext : DbContext {

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        bool hasChanges = false;

        this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        #region Fill Created, Changed

        foreach (var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted)))
        {
            if (item.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                hasChanges = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Id
                PropertyInfo pI = item.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
                if (pI != null)
                {
                    Guid id = (Guid)pI.GetValue(item.Entity, null);
                    if ((Guid)id == Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        id = Guid.NewGuid();
                        pI.SetValue(item.Entity, id);
                    }
                }

                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                // Timestamp & User
                pI = item.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate");
                if (pI != null)
                {
                    var date = pI.GetValue(item.Entity, null);
                    // Only if empty on new records
                    if (date == null || date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
                    {
                        pI.SetValue(item.Entity, now);
                        pI = item.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedUser");
                        if (pI != null)
                        {
                            pI.SetValue(item.Entity, Environment.UserName); 
                        }
                    }
                    pI = item.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("ChangedDate");
                    if (pI != null)
                    {
                        pI.SetValue(item.Entity, now);
                    }
                    pI = item.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("ChangedUser");
                    if (pI != null)
                    {
                        pI.SetValue(item.Entity, Environment.UserName); 
                    }
                }

                hasChanges = true;

            }

        }

        #endregion

        int countChanges = 0;

        if (hasChanges)
        {
            // Call SaveChanges Method from Context;
            try
            {
                countChanges = base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
        return countChanges;
    }
}
```

For new records that works perfectly, but not for modified ones.

The new datetime value in the `ChangedDate` field appears only in the context but does not write to database.
If I step through the code, I see `item.State` is `EntityState.Modified` and the `countChanges` return value is 1 and the value in `item.Entity` everything seems correct.
If query the object the new value is visible but the value in database does not change, so if I dispose my context the old value will reappear.

Really confusing is the fact that the field value I change in the ui to test it *is* changed in the db, but not the field `ChangedDate`.

Why?

Here is a example of one entity class and the configuration, created by Devarts Entity Devloper:

```
public partial class Abo {

    public Abo()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    #region Properties

    public virtual global::System.Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // ...

    public virtual global::System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ChangedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual global::System.Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string CreatedUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string ChangedUser
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}   


public partial class AboConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Abo>
{

    public AboConfiguration()
    {
        this
            .HasKey(p => p.Id)
            .ToTable("Abos", "dbo");
        // Properties:
        this
            .Property(p => p.Id)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
                .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

        // ...
        this
            .Property(p => p.CreatedDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime");
        this
            .Property(p => p.ChangedDate)
                .HasColumnType("datetime");
        this
            .Property(p => p.CreatedUser)
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");
        this
            .Property(p => p.ChangedUser)
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .HasColumnType("varchar");

        OnCreated();
    }

    partial void OnCreated();

}
```

The SQL DDL of the corresponding table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Abos](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
/* .. */
    [ChangedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ChangesUser] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [CreatedUser] [varchar](32) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Abos] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Looking at the wrong databse? It is a known issue when using the internal db server that the website runs a COPY that gets reset on every project start.

Comment: We use  a ConnectString from app.config to establish the db connection. 
`connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Abo; Integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"`
How a wrong db server could be used? Btw. its a WinForms app.

Comment: I don't see any Unit of Work here. UoW means creating a new context, doing stuff with it, calling `SaveChanges()` and disposing it. This looks like an attempt to *bypass* `SaveChanges` (why?) by ... reimplementing the autogenerated ID feature? All of these things are already available in EF, easily configurable with attributes or in the context's configuration methods. Are you trying to add *auditing columns* to an entity?

Comment: Where is the *context's* configuration? Does the the `ChangedDate` property exist in the *entity*? Is it mapped in the configuration? Why implement the auditing properties in the *client* instead of using triggers and default constraints on the server?

Comment: We use the UoW approach to have a several functions on each entity e.g. like `GetNextNr` but only to have it once implemented, but this is offtopic here and works well. 
The reason for this inherited `class OwnContext` is to implement the auto filling of `ChangedDate` and `ChangedUser` fields.

Comment: Sure there is a configuration an a mapped field in there. Again for new records that works perfectly!

Comment: @PixelHunter so you are asking about *auditing* fields, not UoW. There are [duplicate SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314620/entity-framework-core-creation-and-update-fields) that show how to do this. The fields *must* exist on the property. Btw `Id` should be configured as an autogenerated property, not in the SaveChanges override. The best/safest way to implement the audit fields is *triggers*, but you can use the SaveChanges override if you accept lost changes because some job or process will *always* have to be run outside your application.

Comment: @PixelHunter other than that, you didn't provide enough info to replicate the problem - entity class, context configuration, table schema?

Comment: @PixelHunter btw SQL Server offers [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) in all versions since 2008 at least and all editions. Instead of two properties that *don't* explain what happened and don't cover deletions, you get the changes, date, reason, keys, and possibly even the column values for a configurable window in the past. The feature is cheap so it can be used to find table changes easily.

Comment: @PixelHunter History tables are another option, also more useful than `CreatedBy/CreatedOn` fields, although they are more expensive and before SQL Server 2017 required triggers to implement. With the system-versioned *temporal tables* in 2017, you can implement a history table easily by making your tables temporal

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 
Change Tracking seems a bit over for our purpose, we want only to see when and who did the last change, there is no need to see *what* was changed.

Of course the are the fields ChangeDate and ChangeUser as property in the entity class and in the db table, I added the source into my question.

Tiggers might me a solution but I am not very used to it, and I like to have the implementation only in one place, so I prefer to have it in c# if possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
The reason why I have implemented Id generation in the SaveChanges is that I expericences that I can access it then rightaway, not have to query for it, sometimes that is useful for me. Do you see any disadvanteges in this approach?

Comment: I guess that at this point, the property changes on the entity object received by the change tracker are not DTO relevant. Have you tried to apply the changes through "item.CurrentValues" ?

Comment: @Patrick Great! That's the solution, please add that as answer.
`item.CurrentValues["ChangedDate"] = DateTime.Now;` does the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, the property changes on the entity object received by the change tracker are not DTO relevant. You need to apply the changes through the `DbEntityEntry.CurrentValues` Property instead.

```
item.CurrentValues["ChangedDate"] = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call context.savechanges to save the data to db

Comment: Please look in the last try..catch there you will find a `base.SaveChanges()`

Comment: thanks, missed it, but it should not be base.SaveChanges(), it should be this.SaveChanges() since the tables are being tracked is on this context, not in the base context.

Comment: I don't think so, because my method should override the `Context.SaveChanges()` from the context but finally I have to call it with `base.SaveChanges()`. Your suggestion to call `this.SaveChanges()` would call my own method recusively which I don't want.